# How to pass multiple GTM tags in gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am using a `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager` plugin for analytics of my site, but later I create another site from the same code base (differentiate its branding based on specific routes), for that, I need to add another GTM tag into my plugin. Now I believe I cannot add any conditions in the `gatsby-config` file (Please correct me if I am wrong), then How do handle this case?  Do I need to add insert script manually using the gatsby-SSR function or is there any other way to resolve it?

```
{
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
    options: {
        id: config.gtm,
        includeInDevelopment: false,
        defaultDataLayer: { platform: "gatsby" },
        enableWebVitalsTracking: true,
    },
},
```

I am passing `gtm` tag as per my build environment via `process.env`

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is using [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) to use a different identifier for each file.

If each project triggers a different environment variable, you will be able to use a different instance of GTM in each build.

After adding:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV}`,
})
```

Your scripts can look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-site-1": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=site1 gatsby build",
    "build-site-2": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=site2 gatsby build",
  },
```

Then, because of `.env.${process.env.GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV}` you can define a `.env.site1` and `.env.site2` in the root of your project to define each GTM identifier:

```
GTM_ID= 1234
```

Finally, in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
    options: {
        id: process.env.GTM_ID,
        includeInDevelopment: false,
        defaultDataLayer: { platform: "gatsby" },
        enableWebVitalsTracking: true,
    },
},
```

The `GTM_ID` will be the one fired by the build command so each file will have each agnostic configuration.

Tweak the approach to fit your specifications but get the idea of the logic separation.

Comment: The project is one so the build is also one for both sites. (/a belongs to a.com and /d belongs to d.com) As data was having the same schema I had kept the same code on gatsby. The whole build is stored in the S3 bucket and we redirect requests (using redirect rules) to s3 via CDN from 2 different sites. If request from a.com redirects to /a and from d.com then /d. Therefore I cannot able to give different env. Moreover, I have tried injecting gtag scripts from SSR. I Will post an answer once I get succeed.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this requirement when I posted the answer. I'll keep it there for those who might be helpful despite it may not work for you. In your given use-case I think the best approach is the one you are trying to. Inject different scripts/IDs based on some SSR conditions. I'd love to see the resolution when you have it